# Using Filter_SANITIZE_FLOAT with FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION but still losing the comma?

Tags: php-7

My issue is that I loses the decimals symbol although I'm using the sanitize float as per PHP documentation.

I've considered using validate instead of sanitize, but heck... it was working in the past implementation of the command, so I just don't get it.

Something I might have missed?

My faulty code Snippet:

```
if (is_numeric($value) && !empty($value) && !is_null($value)){
     $temp[$key] = filter_var($value,FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
    var_dump($value, $temp[$key]);
}
```

[A capture of my var_dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5kMt.png)

Comment: Oh... I found that on https://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_sanitize_number_float.asp comma is a thousand separator... I am a french Canadian, we use comma as decimals, so I overlooked this detail.

My issue most certainly comes from my database's locale then because these babies are periods at first, then they becomes somewhere along the way a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 solutions for the issue after all...

1- Play with the locale... as I found out my project manager has required the local to be as following : setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_CA.utf-8'); so it confirms that comma are decimal characters. I suspect that PHP is not adaptable in this situation if my local changes the decimal symbol, PHP will still seek for a period using 'filter_var('.

2- filter_var($value,FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION | FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND ); it allows both comma and period, so it kinda  work around the issue...

I'll go post this on PHP official site to warn other folks that might get the same issue I was having...